# What object or class to pass in Factory method in domain package returning objects of Service layer?

Tags: reflection, domain-driven-design, factory-method

I've a domain package which has an interface called `MyInterface`. I also have a factory class called `MyFactory`, which should help in creating instances of classes that implement MyInterface, at runtime.

Domain Layer

```
interface MyInterface{
    //some Domain specific methods here
}

class MyFactory{
    public static MyInterface getInstance(Object resource) {

    // return MyInterfaceImpl instance via the methods 
    // this Object can also be a Class argument, where I do 
    // Class.forName("").newInstance(); but this is a bad design.
}


class DomainServiceImpl {
    public void domainMethod(Object res) {
        MyInterface i = MyFactory.getInstance(res);
    }
}
```

Service layer

```
class Class1 implements MyInterface {

}

class Class2 implements MyInterface {

}

class ServiceClass {
    public void service() {
        domainServiceImpl.domainMethod(Object res);
    }
}
```

So how should I write my factory method in domain layer to get the correct  instance of service layer without using if/else or switch and avoiding cyclic dependencies.

Options: can use reflections but not sure how to.

Comment: What is the "correct impl"? When and based on which criteria will that decision be made?

Comment: Suppose, Ive different versions of resource and I've got one impl for each version, then I would like to instantiate the correct impl for that resource version.

Comment: Where does `ServiceClass.service()` get the resource from? Do you mean version as in versions of your source code at different points in time?

Comment: Service layer will have a dependency of the resource layer, so it can access the resources, but domain layer does not have any dependencies

Comment: I kind of understand why you gave `res` the `Object` type now... but this is not how you'd do it. Domain layer is only concerned with *domain* logic and data structures. Normally, it only uses types that are declared internally. As an input, it can take primitive types (int, string, etc.) or domain types but that's it.

Comment: Maybe elaborate in your Q about why Domain layer needs stuff from the Resource layer and and how the concept of "version" requires multiple service implementations with different logic in them.

Answer (score 0):

> So how should I write my factory method in domain layer to get the correct instance of service layer without using if/else or switch and avoiding cyclic dependencies.

The concept you are looking for is called "Dependency Injection".  [Misko Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/11/clean-code-talks-dependency-injection/) published a lot of accessible material on this subject.

In the domain layer, you define interfaces for the *service providers*, and inject those service providers into your implementations via constructors

```
interface MyFactory {
    public MyInterface getInstance(Object resource);
}

class DomainServiceImpl {
    final MyFactory factory;

    // "Dependency Injection"
    public DomainServiceImpl(MyFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory
    }

    public void domainMethod(Object res) {
        MyInterface i = MyFactory.getInstance(res);
    }
}
```

Then from the outside, you can implement the factory that you need.

```
class Class1MyFactory implements MyFactory {
    public MyInterface getInstance() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

And inject it at the appropriate point in the service

```
class ServiceClass {
    final domainServiceImpl;

    public ServiceClass(DomainServiceImpl domainServiceImpl) {
        this.domainServiceImpl = domainServiceImpl;
    }

    public void service() {
        domainServiceImpl.domainMethod(Object res);
    }
}
```

So when it is time to construct the service, you choose your dependencies and away you go....

```
MyFactory myFactory = new Class1MyFactory(...);
DomainServiceImpl domainServiceImpl = new DomainServiceImpl(myFactory)
ServiceClass service = new ServiceClass(domainServiceImple)
```